# Issue with json conversions for scalax graph library for scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

We are using **graph-json 1.11.0** and **graph-core-1.11.5** with in a **play 2.5.x** application .

http://www.scala-graph.org/

The user guide examples for toJson and fromJson for a graph , do not wok with the current stable 1.11.0 release .
Ref : http://www.scala-graph.org/guides/json.html

We make use of a simple string graph in our application 
**Graph[String,DiEdge]** .

We managed to write the graph to json conversion part , but unable to identify the exact fromJson syntax for the new stable version .

Below is a sample code used in our application . Can some one help us on how to convert json to graph.

```
import play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, Json}
import scalax.collection.Graph
import scalax.collection.GraphEdge.DiEdge
import scalax.collection.io.json.JsonGraph
import scalax.collection.io.json.descriptor.Descriptor
import scalax.collection.io.json.descriptor.predefined.Di
import scalax.collection.io.json.descriptor.{Descriptor, StringNodeDescriptor}

object HierarchyGraph {
  val descriptor = new Descriptor(StringNodeDescriptor,Di.descriptor[String]())

  def toJson(graph : Graph[String, DiEdge]) : JsValue = {
    val jsText = JsonGraph(graph).toJson(descriptor)
    try {
      Json.parse(jsText)
    } catch {
      case e : Exception => Json.toJson(Json.obj())
    }
  }

  def fromJson(graphAsJsValue : JsValue) : Graph[String,DiEdge] = {
   // json  to graph conversion code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue addressed by peter-empen on github . 
https://github.com/scala-graph/scala-graph/issues/71